# Failure to launch Internet Explorer 11 using selenium 2.47.1

Tags: java, windows, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am getting the following error when I run this code in my automation suite,

- Selenium 2.47.1
- Internet Explorer 11
- OS: Windows 8

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Exception Trace:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.47.1',
>   revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44' System info: host: 
>   os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_51' Driver info: driver.version:
>   InternetExplorerDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting
>   for driver server to start. Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision:
>   'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44' System info: host:  os.name:
>   'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_51' Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed
>   out waiting for [http://localhost:23905/status] to be available after
>   20005 ms  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:167)
>     ... 50 more Caused by:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
>     ... 52 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by configuring the system property for the internet explorer driver,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
```

And changed the protected mode setting to be same for all the zones.